# Using setTimeout in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, settimeout, clock

I have written this code to design digital clock in jQuery but somewhere I am skipping main code so unable to get result.

```
 $( window ).load(function() {


    setTimeout(function(){

    var now=new Date();
    var clock= now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + 
      now.getSeconds();
      $("#print").text(clock);
        },1000);
   });
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`**

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
        setInterval(function(){
         var now=new Date();
         var clock= now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" +  now.getSeconds();
         $("#print").text(clock);
        },1000);
    });
```